# Netlify's Not Found Page (link broken)

Tags: netlify

I have just started using netlify and its been giving me a 404 not found page.Apparently the link is broken. I looked on the Netlify Community and they said that there was no index.html present. This isn't true BEFORE the deploy but after, it disappears. I've been trying to solve the problem but with no avail. Please could someone help?[Picture of before deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BblPf.png)

Comment: Can you provide the link of the deployed app

Answer (score 3):

Easy fix;

In your root directory, create a _redirects file;

Add this;

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

This should fix the issue for React apps hosted on Netlify.

Source: https://devsntechies.com/fix-page-not-found-error-on-netlify-app/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to update some of Netlify's Build Settings - see docs here: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/

It looks like you're using `react-scripts`, so the `Build command` on Netlify should be `yarn build` and the `Publish directory` should be `build`.

**Update:** If you are using Netlify's drag and drop functionality instead of its build & deploy pipeline, you need to make sure that the folder you are dragging is the one named `build`, so the `index.html` is at the root of the site.

Comment: I've read your comment and I don't really understand The last part of the comment.

Comment: Have a read through those docs linked. To help further, I'd need to see your fill package.json file, and what settings you currently have set up in Netlify.

Comment: How would I show you my settings on netlify

Comment: go to https://app.netlify.com/sites/<sitename>/settings/deploys

Comment: https://ibb.co/f0LnZyc
https://ibb.co/nztbQ3R
https://ibb.co/bXnK9zD

Comment: that says you're not even set up for deployments, how are you deploying your site?

Comment: oh i'm just adding then deleting the site. should I set it up?

Comment: howare you adding it? if you drag your build folder into the deployments screen that also works

Comment: i delete the site then add another one

Comment: ok ill do that next time but the problem?

Comment: Also addressing the last part, I do drag the build folder